# Python basemap change resolution upon zoom

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming, resolution, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to change the resolution of a map when the user zooms in order to save on memory and processing time. I've tried the following code, but even though the map resolution gets changed each time you zoom, the figure does not update and I am stuck with the coarse resolution. Any ideas on how to force the map to update its resolution when the user zooms? Thanks!

Here's the code I've tried:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create new figure, axes instances
fig = plt.figure(dpi=150)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
# setup mercator map projection
map = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-58,urcrnrlat=80,
              llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')

map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.50)
map.fillcontinents()
map.drawmapboundary()

# Declare and register callbacks for zoom control
def on_lims_change(axes):
    xrange = abs(ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0])
    yrange = abs(ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0])

    # try to change map resolution based on zoom level
    if max(xrange,yrange) < 1E7 and max(xrange,yrange) > 1E6: # 'l' = low
        map.resolution = 'l'
    elif max(xrange,yrange) < 1E6 and max(xrange,yrange) > 5E5: # 'i' = intermeditate
        map.resolution = 'i'
    elif max(xrange,yrange) < 5E5 and max(xrange,yrange) > 1E5: # 'h' = high
        map.resolution = 'h'
    elif max(xrange,yrange) < 1E5: # 'f' = full
        map.resolution = 'f'
    else: # 'c' = coarse
        map.resolution = 'c'

    print(map.resolution)
    map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.50)
    map.fillcontinents()
    map.drawmapboundary()

ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_lims_change)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try adding a `fig.canvas.draw()` at the end of your `on_lims_change()` function. Also, I think you don't need to redraw the boundaries every time.

Answer (score 2):

Best way I found was to call something like

```
zoomcall = ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', onzoom)
ax.patches.clear()
ax.collections.clear()
ax.callbacks.disconnect(zoomcall)
```

in order to (1) establish callback, (2) clear the old map and (3) clear the callback. This is done as part of a new class for ease of use.

Here is the code outline:

```
class ZoomPlot():

    def __init__(self, pnts):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.bnds = self.bnds_strt = [-58, 80, -180, 180]
        self.resolution = 'c'

        self.plot_map()

    def plot_map(self):
        self.map = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=self.bnds[0],urcrnrlat=self.bnds[1],
                      llcrnrlon=self.bnds[2],urcrnrlon=self.bnds[3],resolution=self.resolution)

        self.map.drawcoastlines()
        self.map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='cornflowerblue')
        self.map.fillcontinents(color='lightgreen', lake_color='aqua')
        self.map.drawcountries()
        self.map.drawstates()

        self.plot_points()

        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        self.zoomcall = self.ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', self.onzoom)

    def onzoom(self, axes):
        #print('zoom triggered')
        self.ax.patches.clear()
        self.ax.collections.clear()
        self.ax.callbacks.disconnect(self.zoomcall)

        x1, y1 = self.map(self.ax.get_xlim()[0], self.ax.get_ylim()[0], inverse = True)
        x2, y2 = self.map(self.ax.get_xlim()[1], self.ax.get_ylim()[1], inverse = True)
        self.bnds = [y1, y2, x1, x2]

        # reset zoom to home (workaround for unidentified error when you press the home button)
        if any([a/b > 1 for a,b in zip(self.bnds,self.bnds_strt)]):
            self.bnds = self.bnds_strt # reset map boundaryies
            self.ax.lines.clear() # reset points
            self.ab.set_visible(False) # hide picture if visible

        # change map resolution based on zoom level
        zoom_set = max(abs(self.bnds[0]-self.bnds[1]),abs(self.bnds[2]-self.bnds[3]))
        if zoom_set < 30 and zoom_set >= 3:
            self.resolution = 'l'
            #print('   --- low resolution')
        elif zoom_set < 3:
            self.resolution = 'i'
            #print('   --- intermeditate resolution')
        else:
            self.resolution = 'c'
            #print('   --- coarse resolution')

        self.plot_map()
```